# Localização de uma variável

Tags: php, laravel

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::view('/teste', 'teste');
Route::get('/noticia/{slug}', function($slug){
    if($slug != null):
        Route::redirect('noticia/{$slug}', '/');
    else:
        echo 'Erro de redirecionamento';
    endif;    
});
```

- A função deve redirecionar o acesso do usuário para a view "welcome", sempre que o valor de $slug for
  igual a vazio ou seja: /noticia/(vazio)
- Quando atribuo um valor a variavel $slug, consigo cair no else, e o script me retorna o echo.

PROBLEMA: Sempre que eu acesso /noticia retorna para mim o erro 404 not found.

PERGUNTA: Onde fica armazenado o valor da variável {$slug}

Answer (score 0):

Nessa sintaxe, o parâmetro slug é obrigatório e como não há rota para /noticia o esperado é realmente 404 como retorno

```
'/noticia/{slug}'
```

Para que se torne opcional você precisa utilizar a seguinte sintaxe

```
'/noticia/{slug?}'
```

Isso é descrito na documentação do Laravel aqui: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-optional-parameters